# Why is my proof incorrect for showing set of all increasing functions $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basically, my reasoning is: we can demonstrate a bijection between the set of all functions $f(x)=x+a$ and natural numbers by mapping each natural number to the function using the corresponding a value. ($1\mapsto x+1$... etc) From there, we can easily show that there are more increasing functions aside from just the $x+a$ set, and thus the cardinality of increasing functions is greater than that of natural numbers.

My friend pointed out this is faulty, using the fact that we can form bijections with $\Bbb N$ for both $\Bbb Z^+$ and $\Bbb Z$.

I was modeling my proof after Cantor Diagonalization, which shows a bijection with a set of real numbers and then demonstrates we can create new real numbers outside of our original bijection. Why is this correct but my proof isn't?

Comment: Cantors proof shows that if there were a bijection then there is a real number which isn't covered by the bijection, which is a contradiction. You just showed that there is an injection from the naturals to the desired set which isn't surjective (the last thing you only noted though).

Comment: @algen that is true but I also showed a bijection between N and a subset of the set of all increasing functions, right? Because I showed all natural numbers have some corresponding mapping in my subset. And then if I mention that there are other increasing functions like f: a*x that are outside my bijection, isn't this the same structure as Cantor's?

Comment: @Michelle the set $\{a\cdot x:a\in\Bbb N\}$ is also countable, and the finite sum or product of countable sets is also countable.

Comment: Look at $g:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$, $n\mapsto 2n$. This doesn't imply that $\mathbb N$ is uncountable. You can use cantor's idea though in this exercise. Assume for sake of contradiction that $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow S$ would be a bijection, where $S$ is the set of inc. functions. Then construct a function $F:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$ s.t. $F(0)=f(0)(0)+1$, $F(1)=max(f(0)(1),f(1)(1))+1$ etc.

Comment: @algen sorry, I don't understand your notation–what are the functions that take 2 arguments?

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb N$ $f(n)$ is an increasing function from $\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$. So for $m\in\mathbb N$ $f(n)(m)$ is the function $f(n)$ evaluated at $m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The critical idea here is that Cantor's diagonalization argument hinges on the fact that it works *no matter which proposed enumeration of the reals you start with*. It's not enough to simply provide a listing that misses some things - if it were, we could show that the *naturals* were uncountable! In order to show that a set $S$ is uncountable, you must show that there is *no* way of assigning a different natural number to each member of $S$, not that the one you happened to choose doesn't work.

Importantly, Cantor's diagonalization does *not* show a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$; it says "suppose that a bijection exists" and then derives a contradiction. Or, if you phrase the argument slightly differently, it says "pick any function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$" and shows that no matter which function you picked, that function is not surjective.

Answer (score 4):

I think the part you missed is that when you apply Cantor diagonalisation, you *can't* specify what your alleged listing of elements is, because the point is to prove that *regardless* of how the list is constructed, it will always miss an element. You usually only construct a list when you want to prove that such a list exists (which is the case when you're trying to show a bijection between sets, e.g. to show that the rationals are countable).

So instead of "Let the list be the functions $x$, $x+1$, $x+2$, ..." you have to say "Suppose there is a list. Let the elements of the list be $f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots$" and work from there.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Natl}{\mathbf{N}}\newcommand{\Incr}{\mathcal{I}}$Let $\Incr$ denote the set of increasing functions from $\Natl$ to itself.

- Your goal is to show either of:

  There does not exist a surjection $\Phi:\Natl \to \Incr$.

  Contrapositively, if $\Phi:\Natl \to \Incr$ is an arbitrary mapping, then $\Phi$ is not surjective.
- You have shown:

  A particular mapping $\Phi:\Natl \to \Incr$ is not a surjection. (Specifically, the mapping $a \mapsto \Phi_{a}$, with $\Phi_{a}(x) = x + a$ for all natural numbers $x$ is not a surjection.)

The gap is, perhaps *some other mapping $\Phi:\Natl \to \Incr$ is surjective*. In other words, you did not consider an *arbitrary* mapping $\Phi:\Natl \to \Incr$.

---

What may help in your situation is to show that:

1. An increasing function $f:\Natl \to \Natl$ is uniquely associated with an *infinite subset* of $\Natl$ (namely, its image).
2. The set of infinite subsets of $\Natl$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

The error is assuming that "there are more". The concept "there are more" must be shown proving that exists a bijection to some uncountable set or, equivalently, that doesnt exists a countable bijection (as the diagonalization theorem does).

Observe that, in the same sense, we can say that the set defined by $\Bbb N_{\ge0}\cup\{\sqrt 2\}$ "have more elements" than $\Bbb N_{\ge 0}$. But the cardinality of a set is defined through bijection with other set. In our case the function $f(n):=\delta_{0,n}(\sqrt2+1)+n-1$ is a bijection from $\Bbb N_{\ge 0}$ to $\Bbb N_{\ge 0}\cup\{\sqrt2\}$, thus both sets have the same cardinality (where $\delta_{j,k}$ is the Kronecker delta).